# Get JSON element swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I am working receiving the following JSON file in Swift and I cant figure out how get the details elements in the JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 143369,
    "history": "jd2",
    "details": [
      {
        "name": "Su 1",
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      {
        "name": "Stu 1",
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 143369,
    "history": "musa 2",
    "details": [
      {
        "name": "Stu 1",
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      {
        "name": "Stu 2",
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have created this class with which I am able to retrieve id and history but not the details. How do I include the details with the id and history?

```
public class students {

    let id: Int32
    let history: String?

    init(id:Int32, history:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.history = name

    }
}
```

Below is my web service code.

```
var dataArray = [students]()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value)
                if let items = json.array {
                    for item in items {
                           self.dataArray.append(students(
                            id: item["id"].int32!,
                            history: item["history"].string!))

                            let cItems = item["details"].array
                                for citem in citems {
                                    //here
                                }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Would you like yo use [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) ? if yes then I can post an answer

Answer (score 1):

your student model should be like this.

```
let id: Int32
let history: String?
let details: Array<[String:AnyObject]>
init(id:Int32, history:String,details:Array<[String:AnyObject]>) {
    self.id = id
    self.history = name
    self.details= details //need a cast here!
}
```

here is a simple parser for i used for a project to cast your Array<[String:AnyObject]> as you

```
func collection(data:[[String:AnyObject]]) -> [yourModel] {

        var objectArray: [yourModel] = []

        for d in data {

            let obj = yourModel(data: d as [String: AnyObject]) // i created a initializer for this object here on my project.

            objectArray.append(obj)

        }

        return objectArray

}
```

hope gives an idea!

Comment: Thanks, I am really new to swift and not sure of how to use this code with my existing code.